# Wss4jSecurityInterceptor - My Custom Callback is interpreted as a CleanupCallback Object

Tags: java, spring, soap, authentication, wss4j

I'm working in a project, made with Java 8 and Spring Boot, in which I want to add the Wss4jSecurityInterceptor for login purposes.

So far, this is what I've done in the WebServiceConfig class

```
@Bean
public AuthorizationCallBackHandler authorizationCallBackHandler(){
    AuthorizationCallBackHandler callbackHandler = new AuthorizationCallBackHandler();
    return callbackHandler;
}
@Bean
public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor(){
    Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
    securityInterceptor.setValidationActions("UsernameToken");
    securityInterceptor.setValidationCallbackHandler(authorizationCallBackHandler());
    return securityInterceptor;
}

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List interceptors) {
        interceptors.add(securityInterceptor());
        //interceptors.add(endPointInterceptor());
    }
```

So, with this, every request that arrives at my Web Service, will be intercepted by the Wss4jSecurityInterceptor and will be handled by my custom callback, defined like this

```
public class AuthorizationCallBackHandler implements CallbackHandler{

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    VnWsCredentialRepository credentialsRepo;

    @Autowired
    AuthUtility authUtil;

    @Override
    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {


        if (callbacks[0] instanceof WSPasswordCallback) {
            WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0];
            String username = pc.getIdentifier();
            VnWsCredential credentials = credentialsRepo.findByUsername(username);
            logger.info("Request of authentication for username" + username);
            String p =              pc.getPassword();
            // set the password on the callback. This will be compared to the
            // password which was sent from the client.
            if (credentials == null) {
                pc.setPassword(null);


            }else {
//              String encodedPsw = authUtil.obtaindMD5Value(credentials.getPassword()); 
//              pc.setPassword(encodedPsw);
                pc.setPassword(credentials.getPassword());
            }

        }

        if (callbacks[0] instanceof UsernameTokenPrincipalCallback) {
            UsernameTokenPrincipalCallback pc = (UsernameTokenPrincipalCallback) callbacks[0];
            pc.getPrincipal();
        }



    }

}
```

Here's my problem: when the Callback gets called, it receives an array that holds just 1 callback with a "CleanupCallback" type and I'm not, of course, able to do anything with it.

What am I missing in the following settings?

This is the SOAP call that I'm making with SOAP UI

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:it="some.fancy.ws">
   <soapenv:Header>
       <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
       <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-3967AEB46D733EF6E2154990461080350">
       <wsse:Username>Just a user</wsse:Username>
       <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">just a password</wsse:Password>
       <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">pUn8VjdpVaIamSAIwXEeXg==</wsse:Nonce>
       <wsu:Created>2019-02-16T17:03:30.803Z</wsu:Created>
       </wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <it:getPOrderRequest>
         <it:poNumber>2197111225-F03292</it:poNumber>
      </it:getPOrderRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I solved this thing by first of all removing from the request the content inside the header.

After that, I setted up an Outgoing WSS with the credentials and, just like that, the Wss4j Security Handler converted the Callback to the instance I wanted (that is, WSPasswordCallback).

**Lesson learned:** if Wss4j detects a some kind of error in handling the SOAP Request, it will generate a CleanupCallback and not an instance of WSPasswordCallback